# how to query in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

i have this document in my collection foo

```
provincia:
  {
    cod_provincia:5,
    nom_provincia:'Cordoba'
  },
 localidad: 
  {
    cod_localidad:107,
    nom_localidad:'Cordoba'
  },
 barrio:
  {
    cod_barrio:0,
    nom_barrio:'Nva Cordoba'
  }
```

i query in mongo prompt like this

```
db.foo.find(
{
provincia:
      {
        cod_provincia:5,
        nom_provincia:'Cordoba'
      },
     localidad: 
      {
        cod_localidad:107,
        nom_localidad:'Cordoba'
      },
     barrio:
      {
        cod_barrio:0,
        nom_barrio:'Nva Cordoba'
      }
})
```

i have this result in my console

```
_id("5041a53dd163651512000001")
```

but when i query

```
db.foo.find(
{
provincia:
      {
        cod_provincia:5

      },
     localidad: 
  {
    cod_localidad:107,
    nom_localidad:'Cordoba'
  },
 barrio:
  {
    cod_barrio:0,
    nom_barrio:'Nva Cordoba'
      }
})
```

i have nothing... why is that???
im trying to understand how can i query all documents
without nom_provincia

tnx all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the dot notation to reach into nested objects:

```
db.test.find({ 
  'provincia.cod_provincia': 5,
  localidad: {
    cod_localidad:107,
    nom_localidad:'Cordoba'
  },
  barrio: {
    cod_barrio:0,
    nom_barrio:'Nva Cordoba'
  }
})
```

More info [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29)

Comment: hooh i see... is posible... this answer is more complete tnx agreco

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
provincia:
      {
        cod_provincia:5
      },
```

searches for a document where the provincia sub-object looks exactly like that, without the nom_provincia field. Use the dot notation instead:

```
'provincia.cod_provincia':5,
```